# selected Value from SelectOneChoice Adf

Tags: richfaces, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to make a selectitems in adf:
when the user choose the "client" he get automaticly the Contrat ID and from that he can add an "assistance".

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.client7.inputValue}"
                                                label="#{bindings.client7.label}"
                                                required="#{bindings.client7.hints.mandatory}"
                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.client7.hints.tooltip}" id="soc1">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.client7.items}" id="si1"/>
                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.client7.validator}"/>
                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                           <af:outputText  partialTriggers="soc1" id="ot1"
                                          value="#{bindings.contratRef.selectedValue}"/>
                        </af:panelFormLayout>
```

Ps: i have a onetomany relation between contrat and assistance and the class contrat have a field named "client" also..
Someone help me please to find a solution

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Show some code and say what you want it to do.

Comment: it's done. i want to get the contratID when i select the client in the "selectonechoice"

Comment: What is contratID, where do you want to get it?